# How many icons does CFBundleAlternateIcons support in Info.plist?

Tags: xcode, info-plist, appicon

Such as the title. Who can tell me how many icons does `CFBundleAlternateIcons` support in Info.plist? Thank you very much!

Comment: You should try it yourself first!